# Delay then execute Task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Quick question, I want to **wait** a second **before launching** an **async task** without a return value.
Is this the right way to do it?

```
Task.Delay(1000)
    .ContinueWith(t => _mq.Send(message))
    .Start();
```

What happens to exceptions?

Comment: Why are you using the async CTP? The final release has been out for a long time. And if you can use an async method, you don't need to use ContinueWith manually - just await the delay. Could you give more context please?

Comment: yes it is the best way.

for exception handling:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980712/what-is-the-best-way-to-catch-exception-in-task
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983779/catch-exception-that-is-thrown-in-different-thread

Comment: @jon: wrong tag :) it's being used inside a windows service.

Comment: @JonSkeet He may be restricted to .Net 4 (for XP compatibility) and not feel comfortable guffing around with compiler and targeting packs. This is similar to my position.

Comment: Even in .NET 4 you can use BCL Async. Acync CTP is only for .NET on VS 2010. BTW there is no need to call `Start()`, `Delay` has already started the task

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First of all, `Start()` only works on the (very rare) `Task`s that were created using the `Task` constructor (e.g. `new Task(() => _mq.Send(message))`). In all other cases, it will throw an exception, because the `Task` is already started or waiting for another `Task`.

Now, probably the best way to do this would be to put the code into a separate `async` method and use `await`:

```
async Task SendWithDelay(Message message)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    _mq.Send(message);
}
```

If you do this, any exception from the `Send()` method will end up in the returned `Task`.

If you don't want to do that, using `ContinueWith()` is a reasonable approach. In that case, exception would be in the `Task` returned from `ContinueWith()`.

Also, depending on the type of `_mq`, consider using `SendAsync()`, if something like that is available.

Comment: *"using `ContinueWith()` is a reasonable approach."* -- The `ContinueWith` is tricky. It's a primitive API that should be used with care, so for anyone who is not a TPL expert the `await` approach is safer. A couple or reasons why the `ContinueWith` is tricky: the [CA2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) directive, and the fact that with an `async` delegate the result is a `Task<Task>` that has to be [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap)ed.

Answer (score 15):

You can catch any exception thrown in the Task if you Wait for the Task to finish:

**Be aware of that your Exception thrown in the Task is going to be the inner one**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Task task = Task.Delay(1000)
                .ContinueWith(t => Program.throwsException());

            task.Wait();     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception:" + ex.Message); // Outputs: Exception:One or more errors occurred.
            Console.WriteLine("Inner exception:" + ex.InnerException.Message); // Outputs: Exception:thrown
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
    static void throwsException()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method started");
        throw new Exception("thrown");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted some code, which publishes two messages on the service bus with a delay between the messages, to run parallel. Here is my code:

```
var _ = _serviceBus.PublishAsync(message1)
        .ContinueWith(async f =>
        {
            if (f.IsFaulted)
            {
                logger.LogError(f.Exception, $"Exception was thrown while publishing message {f.Id}");                
            }
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            var _ = _serviceBus.PublishAsync(message2)
            .ContinueWith(f =>
            {
                logger.LogError(f.Exception, $"Exception was thrown while publishing message {f.Id}");
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.Default);
        }, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

Comment: Take a look at the guideline [CA2008: Do not create tasks without passing a TaskScheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008). The `ContinueWith` method is [low level](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html), and needs to be handled with care.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! For me it's ok if the default Thread pool is used (I don't have a ui thread). Would it be better then to pass the TaskScheduler.Default as the TaskScheduler? `.ContinueWith(..., TaskScheduler.Default)`

Comment: Yes, by specifying explicitly the `TaskScheduler.Default` you ensure that the continuation will be scheduled on a well known scheduler. The code is no longer sensitive to the ambient `TaskScheduler.Current`, whatever that may be. Making `TaskScheduler.Current` the default was an unfortunate design decision when the `ContinueWith` API was introduced, and now we are stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to observe any exceptions if you `Wait` for the task.

> Unhandled exceptions that are thrown by user code that is running
>   inside a task are propagated back to the joining thread, except in
>   certain scenarios that are described later in this topic. Exceptions
>   are propagated when you use one of the static or instance Task.Wait or
>   Task.Wait methods, and you handle them by enclosing the call
>   in a try-catch statement.

**Excerpt from [Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx)**

Be careful with timings. Tasks use a scheduler and are not guaranteed to start when your say 'go'. You code will guarantee *at least* 1000ms delay after telling it to `Start` but it is not guaranteed to be 1000ms *exactly*.