# AsyncContext -> AsyncContextThread handling exceptions

Tags: c#, async-await, windows-services

Regarding: `AsyncContextThread`

https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext

https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/AsyncContextThread.cs

It's not really covered how to handle catching exceptions that occur when the thread is started.

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    private readonly AsyncContextThread _thread = new AsyncContextThread();

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public MyService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }    

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {     
            _thread.Factory.Run(StartAsync);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            // Exception?
        }
    }

    private async Task StartAsync()
    {
        throw new Exception("things went wrong");
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (!_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
            _cts.Cancel();
        _thread.JoinAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

I don't seem to catch anything in the `catch{}` block, in addition I tried adding these to my Program.cs (main entry point).

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

However neither of the event handler methods are triggered in the above code.

Q) How do you handle exceptions correctly in this situation?

As a side note, I'm fairly sure that using `AsyncContext` previously and debugging in Visual Studio did catch the exception, so I'm not sure if there's some sync. context I'm missing, when trying to add a handler for exceptions.

**EDIT**

I know I can `try/catch` within the `StartAsync` method, but the point I'm getting at is being able to catch any unhandled Exceptions and make sure I can log them.

Comment: I'm desperately hoping for a Stephen Cleary answer to this question :)

Comment: I think you need to `await` the method in the `try` for the exception to be caught. At the moment the async method will return to the caller immediately and the error thrown is lost.

Comment: @Equalsk you cannot `await` anything in the `OnStart` method of a Windows Service as it's an override and must match the signature expected.

The whole idea of AsyncContext/AsyncContextThread (as far as I understand) is to allow you to spin up async methods from places that wouldn't allow it (i.e. Console apps or Windows services).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to catch exception in Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980712/what-is-the-best-way-to-catch-exception-in-task)

Comment: @TiagoSousa disagree, this is specific to Stephen's AsyncContext classes.

Comment: I marked it as duplicated because the answer to the other question contains the same answer to this one: `task.ContinueWith(t => { /* error handling */ }, context, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);`, which was also the answer to this one.
The fact that you are using the `AsyncContext` classes doesn't change the fact that you want to know how to handle an error on the execution of a `System.Threading.Task` (on the awaiting side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been meaning to do a blog post on asynchronous Win32 services... for a few years now... :)

> It's not really covered how to handle catching exceptions that occur when the thread is started.

The `AsyncContextThread` is actually started immediately upon creation. What you're doing on `OnStart` is queueing work to its context.

The exception for that work is observed on the `Task` returned from `Run`, and the appropriate way to observe it is using `await`:

```
protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {     
        await _thread.Factory.Run(StartAsync);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        // Exception!
    }
}
```

A few notes:

Normally, you should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). The exception to that rule is event handlers or event-like methods (such as `OnStart`). When you *do* use `async void`, you should consider having a `try`/`catch` around the entire `async void` method body (which we do).

[`await` is superior to `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html). In this particular case, `ContinueWith` will work OK, but in the general case it's not advisable: it does not understand `async` delegates, it does not use an appropriate default `TaskScheduler`, and it does not use appropriate default continuation flags. These are all things that `await` just handles for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen, just a follow up, I've got the 'public void Start()' method to kick things off when running in debug from Visual Studio, should I be trying to get the awaiter and it's result, or just leave it as service.Start();?

Comment: I think you'd have to use `Start()`. Since it doesn't return a task, you can't block on it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a [Continuation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks) to handle exceptions.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _thread.Factory.Run(StartAsync).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        var aggregate = t.Exception.Flatten();
        foreach(var exception in aggregate.InnerExceptions)
        {
            // Handle exception
        }
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
}
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying, the reason I think I was hoping to get Stephen's input on the question is that his book "Concurrency in C# Cookbook" (page 35/36) discussed handling exceptions in async void type methods. The code example given doesn't use continuations as you've shown but rather the try/catch in my code sample, therefore this doesn't seem correct.