# Why method has to be async task to catch exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, task

I've got method which I want to **run asynchronously:**

```
public async Task Send(MemoryMapModel memoryMap, SerialPort serialPort, ProgressBar progressBar, Settings settings)
{
    SendFrames(memoryMap, serialPort, progressBar, _token.Token, settings);
}
```

And I use it like this by **Task.Run():**

```
await Task.Run(async () => await _rtuLogic.Send(memoryMap, serialPort, pbProgressBar, settings).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

Method "**Send**" throws exceptions which I want to catch, but to do that, it has to be async Task, but there are *no awaitable methods* and VS wants me not to use *async* keyword.

Why can't I catch exceptions from `Task.Run(() => void)` but it do works for `Task.Run(async () => async Task)`, though there are no awaitable methods?

EDIT:
Also when I tried

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { _rtuLogic.SendAsync(memoryMap, serialPort, pbProgressBar, settings); });
```

I can't catch and handle exceptions.
If I don't use Task.Run(...) Send doesn't run asynchronously and freezes GUI.

Comment: why do you need `await Task.Run(async () => await ...)`? why don't you just `await _rtuLogic.Send(..)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to catch exception in Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980712/what-is-the-best-way-to-catch-exception-in-task)

Comment: `await _rtuLogic.Send(..)` doesn't make the code run asynchronously. It freezes GUI.

Comment: `var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<StateObject>(() => { /* action */ });` is almost the same as `Task.Run(...)`

Comment: I don't think your method needs to be `async`, but if you call it using `Task.Run()`, you do need to `await` it in order to get the exceptions it might throw.

Comment: Where are you calling this from? `await Task.Run(...)` should be correct and not block. Alternatively try the continuation style: `Task.Run(...).ContinueWith(t => ...)`

Comment: But when i do not use `async Task Send(...)` I can't catch and handle exceptions.

Comment: That is not true. Roughly a method that does `DoA();await SomeAsync();DoB()` translates to `DoA();await SomeAsync().ContinueWith(_ => DoB())`. See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_ContinueWith_System_Action_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) You get the task passed into your callback and can do t.Exception to see the exception.`

Comment: I'm calling it from GUI. It's button click event.

Comment: You can't use SendFrames to achieve what you want, it is straight up broken. You need to rewrite it. The problem with it is, that is has 2 concerns that directly conflict under your requirements. SendFrames updates the UI and it does I/O bound operations on the same thread.

Comment: This is the class of problem that async await was designed specifically to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people may see it as a bit outdated now we have `async`, but you seem to be throwing `async`/`await` in everywhere and hoping it'll solve your problem.<sup>1</sup>

So I'd suggest ditching this attempt and look at using [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead. It lets you clearly separate the bits that should happen "elsewhere" from the bits that still need to access the UI and should help avoid blocking it.

`Task.Run` should generally be avoided unless you have CPU bound work that you want to move off the current thread.

If you do want to go `async`/`await` then ideally you find the async variant of `SendFrames` and use that instead. But if that's not available/written yet then don't try to *pretend* that it's async.

---

<sup>1</sup>A now deleted answer linked to [this answer by Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013523/when-correctly-use-task-run-and-when-just-async-await/18015586#18015586) which in turn links off to other articles/posts about async, which I'd suggest you should try to ready all of them and other Stephen Cleary blog posts too ([There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) should always be a recommended read)

Comment: Thank you very much! Background solved the problem,